# Win 10 - Display where Known Folder ?FOLDERID_Documents points to via Command line or Powershell

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-10-v1703

Does anyone know a method for displaying where the Known Folder `?FOLDERID_Documents` currently points to within Windows 10 (Version 1703)?

I need a method than can be carried out from the DOS Command line or from Powershell, as I am trying to troubleshoot a problem on a machine that will not allow me to use anything more groovy.

I'm not really a Powershell user so if I would ask for a nice and gentle approach if that is the way to go.

Is it possible to expose the value of `?FOLDERID_Documents` with VB Script?

I understand that `?FOLDERID_Documents` is not an environment variable in the traditional sense. I also know that the environment variable `%USERPROFILE%` may point to the root location of where `?FOLDERID_Documents` points to, but I live in hope that there must be a simple way of displaying the value of `?FOLDERID_Documents` with a nice simple command.

According to the Microsoft Dev Centre (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid):

> KNOWNFOLDERID constants represent GUIDs that identify standard folders
> registered with the system as Known Folders. These folders are
> installed with Windows Vista and later operating systems, and a
> computer will have only folders appropriate to it installed.

It would appear that ***some*** applications, like SAS Version 9.4, make use of these KNOWNFOLDERIDs to direct themselves to the physical locations represented by generic folder such as `My Documents` and other applications do not. My problem is that for a pair of my SAS users, their Windows 10 installations appear to have suddenly forgotten where `?FOLDERID_Documents` points to. They have only had this problem in the last few days.

As this problem is not affecting all users, I am trying to find a simple way to expose the value held by `?FOLDERID_Documents` on an affected and an un-affected Windows installation so that I can raise it with our in-house technical support.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Personal
```

Comment: You might want to explain what this key does exactly.  Your question has appeared in the low quality review queue due to it's length and content.

Comment: Not sure whether to edit it in, but the output of this command consists of the same registry key path entered on the command line, followed by     `Personal    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\Documents`. The [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) Microsoft webpage does confirm that this is the default path of `FOLDERID_Documents`.

Comment: However, older FOLDERID values do not correspond to values in this Registry key, so it's not generally applicable (for example: `FOLDERID_DeviceMetadataStore` can't be queried like this.).